# Instanciar um objeto de uma classe dentro do contrutor de outra classe

Tags: javascript, classes

[RESOLVIDO]Como que eu instancio o objeto Mars dentro da classe Rover? 
Pois, está me retornando o seguinte erro: "Mars is not defined"

```
class Rover{

  constructor(orderedX,orderedY,orientation,toMove){
    this.orderedX = orderedX;
    this.orderedY = orderedY;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.toMove = toMove;
    this.marsZise = new Mars(5,5);
    this.running();

  }

class Mars{
  constructor(sizeX,sizeY){
    this._orderedlengthX = sizeX;
    this._orderedlengthY = sizeY;

  }
```

Comment: Please redirect your question for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Thanks :)

Comment: estás a usar `typescript`? se sim, apenas faça: `Rover extends Mars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que reparei, você está utilizando `typescript`, para herdar a `classe`, basta usar o `extends` da seguinte maneira:

```
Rover extends Mars
```

Comment: Resolvi aqui, na verdade não queria herdar, errei ao passar os propriedades do objeto Rover por parâmetro no Mars :( (Lógica errada aí)
Queria apenas instanciar o objeto mars dentro do contrutor Rover, ai fica :
this.marsSize = new Mars(5,5) - mudei a logica na classe Mars- 

Obrigada

Comment: Usando ECMAScript6

Comment: @ttlelis_12 isso ai :)